# At which point in the control flow is the NSUnknownKeyException error thrown in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have seen this error several times in my code and I am confused which part of the code is throwing the error. Is this a compiler error or a runtime error? And if it is a compiler error, is the error contained within the xib file (ie the error can be found by the compiler by only looking at the xib file) or is it that the variable names in my code do not match the variables in the xib. And if it is a runtime error, at which point in the control flow is it thrown?

Comment: Do you have a storyboard? 
What is the exact error?

Comment: My current error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x7fbfead06cc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key titleLabel.' but I am asking a more general question about the nature of the error itself.

Comment: I read somewhere that can be cause by a missing IBAction on the property titleLabel linked to the storyboard.